# Add active class to anchors inside list with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i'm using AdminLTE v3 and I can't add active state to menu items with jquery. I searched but there's only examples for v2 and the the anchors are the ones with the active class instead the list items.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">
    <li class="nav-header text-center pb-1"><strong>Menu de Navegação</strong></li>
    <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
            <i class="fas fa-clipboard-list"></i>
                <p>Artigos
                     <i class="right fas fa-angle-left"></i>
                </p>
        </a>
        <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="/Account/Users/NovoArtigo.aspx" class="nav-link animsition-link">
                    <i class="fas fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                    <p>Novo Artigo</p>
                </a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
                 <a href="/Account/Users/ListarArtigos.aspx" class="nav-link animsition-link">
                     <i class="fas fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                    <p>Listar Artigos</p>
                 </a>
             </li>
         </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

here is the jquery used in AdminLTE v2, i just changed the classes names according to the ones in v3

```
var url = window.location;

// for sidebar menu entirely but not cover treeview
$('ul.nav-sidebar a > i').filter(function () {
    return this.href == url;
}).parent().siblings().removeClass('active').end().addClass('active');

// for treeview
$('ul.nav-treeview a').filter(function () {
    return this.href == url;
}).parentsUntil(".nav-sidebar > .has-treeview").siblings().removeClass('active').end().addClass('active')
```

**EDIT**

```
$('ul.nav-sidebar a').filter(function () {
    return this.href == url;
}).addClass('active');
```

this one seems to be working for the anchors insde the nav-treeview. Can't access to the anchor inside the 2nd list item.

With this one I can set all anchors with active

```
var c = $('.nav li a').each(function () {
   return this.href == url;
}).addClass('active');
```

Comment: Run the second function before the first.

Comment: same result, i don't think i'm accessing to the anchors though, i tried using debug to check which element is returned and never returns me the anchor element

Comment: `<i>` has no `href` and it's parent `<a>` has no siblings

Comment: I tried playing around with jquery, i can get the list element but i can't figure out how to reach the anchor

Answer (score 0):

Yes!!!! I finally figured out how the parent child sibling works in jquery!

This is the end result if someone has the same issue and is new to jquery. Also debugger is your best friend.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var url = window.location;

// Adds active on inner anchor and treeview anchor and treeview menu-open state to li
$('ul.nav a').filter(function () {        
    return this.href == url;
}).addClass('active').parent().parent().siblings().addClass('active').parent().addClass('menu-open');
```

});